# Fit a curve to a specific range on a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting

I collect data from a profilometer and try to fit collected data to an ideal curve. The purpose is to get Radius of Curvature.

The code I wrote will fit a curve on all raw data.

Fitting on whole range

[image]

The problem is want specify a range to do the fitting. i.e.: all profilometer data are not suitable for fitting. in the following example, I want to fit on from x= 180 to x = 380

Fitting on specified range

[image]

Of course, having a point and click to specify x_start and x_end would be more helpful, but I failed to extract the data from [onclick](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)

Bonus: if I can display R² while changing fitting range, that would be awesome!

Thanks for your help

Here is the code I came up with:

```
#importing modules
import tkinter.filedialog as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

#Graphic properties
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.45)
#Search and open desired file:
def openfile():
    opennm = tk.askopenfile()
    f = open(opennm.name,"r")
    data=np.genfromtxt(f,
                   skip_header=6,
                   names=True,
                   dtype=None,
                   delimiter=',')
    x=[]
    y=[]

    for i in range(0,len(data)-1):
            x.append(data[i][0])
            y.append(data[i][1])
    return x,y
#after opening the file, x and y data are plotted
x,y=openfile()           
k,= plt.plot(x,y)

#Define the fitting function
def func(x,ROC,x_shift,y_shift):
    return ((ROC*1000)-((ROC*1000)**2-(x-x_shift)**2)**0.5-y_shift)*1000
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=[45,250,0.8],bounds=((1,100,0),(100,300,2))) #, bounds=((-np.inf,10**-8,-np.inf,-np.inf),(np.inf,3.,np.inf,np.inf))

#The fitted curve will be overlaid on raw data
l, = plt.plot(x,func(x,*popt),'r--')

list_of_para=['ROC','X shift','Y shift']
list_of_units=['mm','a.u.','um']
for i in range (0,3):
    print (list_of_para[i],'= ',"%.2f" %popt[i],' ', list_of_units[i])

#definig initial values
ROC0 = popt[0]
x_shift0 = popt[1]
y_shift0 = popt[2]

#defining sliders
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axROC= plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.75, 0.02], facecolor=axcolor)
axx_shift= plt.axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.75, 0.02], facecolor=axcolor)
axy_shift= plt.axes([0.15, 0.25, 0.75, 0.02], facecolor=axcolor)

#define slider limites
sROC = Slider(axROC, 'ROC', popt[0]-np.absolute(popt[0]),popt[0]+np.absolute(popt[0]), valinit=ROC0)
sx_shift = Slider(axx_shift, 'X Shift', popt[1]-np.absolute(popt[1]), popt[1]+np.absolute(popt[1]), valinit=x_shift0)
sy_shift = Slider(axy_shift, 'Y shift', popt[2]-np.absolute(popt[2]), popt[2]+np.absolute(popt[2]), valinit=y_shift0)

#define slider update values
def update(val):
    ROC = sROC.val
    x_shift = sx_shift.val
    y_shift = sy_shift.val
    l.set_ydata(((ROC*1000)-((ROC*1000)**2-(x-x_shift)**2)**0.5-y_shift)*1000)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
sROC.on_changed(update)
sx_shift.on_changed(update)
sy_shift.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Note: you can get an example of profilometer data from here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgMbHdCbxV3LatCuPSJpioDD0w0

Comment: How about truncating  the raw data?  And please specify your question.

Comment: It is difficult to truncate the data because from sample to sample, the "data of interest" might be located at different Xs

Basically I want to learn how to select a range of data directly from my graph (either using point and click, or using a slider) and perform the fitting on that specific range


Sorry if my question was not clear

Comment: My open source Python 3 tkinter GUI curve and surface fitter might have some code you would find useful, and it is BSD licensed. The URL is https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/tkinterFit - you can try using the source code for a starting point that already creates matplotlib scatterplots and fitted model plots in a GUI application.

Comment: Using the data you posted, I found a single equation with 5 parameters as y = f(x) that might be useful: y= B0 + ((B1 - B0) / (1.0 + exp((B2 + x + (B4 * x * x)) * B3))) with parameter values B0 = -7.9384178397884671E+02, B1 = -1.5270563536702939E+01, B2 = -1.1124759182908538E+02, B3 = 1.3469645323833809E-01, B4 = -1.7928899581288380E-03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for all comments and answers

I could figure out another way to work it out (the explanation might be long, so i preferred post as answer instead of simply editing the question)

Bear with me i am coding **only for 3 months**, and i am glad to get your support on this:

So, instead of using slider to adjust my fitting curve, i used a point-&-click to determine the range where i want to perform the fitting **(I will have 2 questions at the end)**

```
import tkinter.filedialog as tk         
import numpy as np                      
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt         
import scipy                            
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit    

fig, ax = plt.subplots()                


def openfile():                         #define function to open file and extract x and y
    opennm = tk.askopenfile()
    f = open(opennm.name,"r")
    data=np.genfromtxt(f,
                   skip_header=6,
                   names=True,
                   dtype=None,
                   delimiter=',')
    x=[]
    y=[]

    for i in range(0,len(data)-1):
            x.append(data[i][0])
            y.append(data[i][1])
    return x,y


x,y=openfile()           
k,= plt.plot(x,y)

coords = []                             #I define the coordinates from where to where i want to run the fitting

def onclick(event):                     #this function to point and click on graph and define fitting area
    global ix, iy
    ix, iy = event.xdata , event.ydata
    print ('x = %d, y = %d'%(
        ix, iy))

    global coords
    coords.append((ix, iy))

    if len(coords) == 2:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
    global l
    for i in coords:
        l,=ax.plot (*i,'ro' )
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    global m
    def find_index(array,value):            #this functions is to find index of my 2 point-and-click data
        global limit
        limit=(np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
        return limit
    limit1=find_index(x,coords[0][0])       #I extract index of Xstart
    limit2=find_index(x,coords[1][0])       #I extraxt index of Xend
    fitx=x[limit1:limit2]                   #From initial x data I extract the range where the fitting will be done
    fity=y[limit1:limit2]                   #From initial y data I extract the range where the fitting will be done

    def func(x,ROC,x_shift,y_shift):        #This si the function I want to fit
        return ((ROC*1000)-((ROC*1000)**2-(x-x_shift)**2)**0.5-y_shift)*1000

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, fitx, fity, p0=[45,250,0.8],bounds=((0.4,100,0),(500,300,2)))    #I run the fitting
    m, = plt.plot(x,func(x,*popt),'r--')    

    print('ROC= ',round(popt[0],0),'mm| X Shift= ', round(popt[1],0),'um| Y Shift= ',round(popt[2],3),'um')
    return coords, l,m

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

**Question 1:**
while running: i select lower limit of fitting range, and before selecting the upper limit I get this message:

> limit2=find_index(x,coords[1][0])       IndexError: list index out of range

which is natural, because I didn't select upper limit YET... how to avoid this annoying error message?

**Question 2:**
after running the fitting, the graph auto-scales... How to fix upper limit of y axis  and keep lower limit in autoscale?

I went through all proposed solutions I found on internet (plt.gca().set_ylim(top=200)...etc) but every time, the lower limit get fixed to 0 automatically

Except these two annoying errors, the program works just fine

once again, I post the link to a test data from my profilometer:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgMbHdCbxV3LatCuPSJpioDD0w0

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot easily truncate the data, you'll need to model all of it.  I haven't tried with your data (it seems to not be posted -- maybe do that?) but it appears that the data could be modeled as

```
Parabola * Rectangle_with_soft_boundaries
```

with the Parabola model giving the radius of curvature you are looking for and Rectangle giving the "truncated background".

You might find lmfit (https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py) useful for this.  It provides a fairly high-level interface to curve-fitting and has many built-in models that can be combined.

For example, you might be able to do something like this:

```
from lmfit.models import RectangleModel

#Define the fitting function
def func(x, roc, x_shift, y_shift):
    return ((roc*1000)-((roc*1000)**2-(x-x_shift)**2)**0.5-y_shift)*1000

# turn model function into model,
# multiply by rectangle with error-function for sides:
model = Model(func) * RectangleModel(prefix='r_', form='erf') 

params = model.make_params(r_amplitude=-600, r_center1=150, 
                           r_center2=375, r_sigma1=10, r_sigma2=10, 
                           roc=45, x_shift=200, y_shift=1)

# you can apply bounds to any of the parameters here:
params['roc'].min = 1
params['roc'].max = 100

params['r_amplitude'].max = 0 # make sure rectangle points down
params['r_center1'].min = 50   
params['r_center1'].max = 250 

# then perform fit
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

# print report of statistics, parameter values
print(result.fit_report())

# plot results
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit)
plt.show()
```

of course, you still sort of need to know some info about where the rectangular background turns on and off -- I suspect this is from some aperture that you probably do know something about (or can figure out!).